# access previous page viewstate in current page using response redirct?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to access the viewstate define in page1 from page2.
Page1 is having response.rediect to page2.

I don't want server.Transfer solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) saves (serialize) the "changed" properties of ASP.NET controls and page during page processing. You should try the `Session` state.